# Extra GROUP BY clause in django query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.8

I've written this Django ORM query:

```
queryset = Test.objects.all() \
    .annotate_test_date() \ # similar to extract hour 
    .annotate_test_time() \ # similar to extract hour 
    .annotate(hour=Extract(F('created_on'), function='hour')) \
    .annotate(count=Count('id')) \
    .order_by() \
    .values('hour', 'count')
```

The resulting query formed is:

```
SELECT extract (hour from ("users_test"."created_on")) AS "hour",
COUNT("users_test"."id") AS "count" 
FROM "users_test" 
GROUP BY "users_test"."id", "users_test"."author_id", "users_test"."created_on", "users_test"."modified_on", "users_test"."access_point_id", "users_test"."user_id", "users_test"."invite_id", "users_test"."building_id", "users_test"."company_id", date("users_test"."created_on"), "time"("users_test"."created_on"), extract (hour from ("users_test"."created_on"))
```

But the required query is:

```
SELECT extract (hour from ("users_test"."created_on")) AS "hour",
COUNT("users_test"."id") AS "count" 
FROM "users_test" 
GROUP BY extract (hour from ("users_test"."created_on"))
```

I believe it is due to the extra annotated fields in my query but those are required for filtering purposes.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try in this order :

```
queryset = Test.objects.all() \
    .annotate(hour=Extract(F('created_on'), function='hour')) \
    .annotate(count=Count('id')) \
    .values('hour', 'count')
    .order_by()
```

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'hour' into field.`

Comment: not even close buddy, this will count on ids which are always unique.

Comment: I am pretty sure this has something to do with this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses